# OpenLayers custom request for WMS GetFeatureInfo

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo

In OpenLayers, there is a `WMSGetFeatureInfo` control that can be attached to a layer and listen to `click` or `hover` events on the map, requesting info on the feature being currently clicked (or pointed) at.

However, how to make a custom `GetFeatureInfo` request, with the following input?

- layer
- [x,y] mouse position OR [lon,lat] position in the map

Is it possible to do this elegantly with the `WMSGetFeatureInfo` control, or do I have to ajax the request myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `WMSGetFeatureInfo` doesn't work by requesting info on the feature being currently clicked as such. It works by formulating a WMS GetFeatureInfo request which passes a BBOX string to the WMS server. So, when you click on the map the location coordinates are captured and then sent to a WMS server as the request. You could see this in action by using something like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) to inspect the request being made.

It is possible to create this elegantly without resorting to Ajax as the control does not have to be associated to a specific layer at creation. You can set the layer on the `beforegetfeatureinfo` event. Something like this would work:

```js
var queryableMapLayers = [];
var getFeatureControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
  url: your_wms_url.here // Your WMS server url here,
  drillDown: false, // Or true if you want drill down (see the docs)
  hover: false, // Or true if you want but bear in mind this could get chatty
  layers: queryableMapLayers,
  eventListeners: {
    getfeatureinfo: function (event) {
      // Code here if you want to process the results
    },
    beforegetfeatureinfo: function(event) {
      // Code here to set the content of queryableMapLayers
      // The event object will contain xy of mouse click
    },
    nogetfeatureinfo: function(event) {
      // Code here if no queryable layers are found
    }
  } 
});

// Add the control to your map
map.addControl(getFeatureControl);
```

We use this approach in our applications along with a custom JSON response from GeoServer to emulate an ArcGIS style feature info dialog.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [request](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo.request) metod of WMSGetFeatureInfo control. Open [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html) example and type in console: `map.controls[4].request(new OpenLayers.Pixel(296,148))`.